# Elasticsearch - Extra unmapped fields on geo-shape type index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some extra inner fields on a geo-shape type field. For example, "shape" is a geo-shape type field which has the regular required fields like "coordinates", "radius" etc., but it may also have other fields like "metadata" which I want elasticsearch to not parse and not store in the index. For example:

```
"shape": {
   "coordinates":[6.77,8.99]
   "radius": 500
   "metadata": "some value"
}
```

Mapping schema looks like this:

```
"shape":{
   "type":"geo_shape"
}
```

How can I achieve this ? By using "dynamic": false on mapping schema does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `dynamic` to `false` in your root mapping, like you did, is the way to go : are your sure it desn't work? Or are you saying that because it appears in your result hit `_source`?

Actually, by default, the `_source` attribute will contains the exact same document that you submitted.

However, it doesn't mean the extra `metadata` field has been indexed and/or stored. 
If you want to check this, request specifically that field in your search like this :

```
POST _search
{
  "fields": ["shape.metadata"]
}
```

You should have your search hits but without any `fields` value.

If it still bother you, disabled the `_source` attribute in your mapping.